# How to copy cells in Visual Studio Code when using Jupyter?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter

I'm working with a Jupyter notebook. How would you copy cells in Visual Studio Code? C to copy and V to Paste did not work for me as it would online.

Also, Visual Studio doesn't seem to offer right click options when working in the notebook. Is there a extension that would give me some options such as Cut, Copy, Paste, Delete Cell, Etc.?

Comment: FYI Jupyter notebook = file format ending with extension .ipynb; Jupyter Lab = interface to work with Jupyter notebooks and general coding/data science tasks. Jupyter Notebook = an older interface to work with jupyter notebooks.

Answer (score 5):

I'm a developer on this extension, and I have a bit of a two part answer for you.

1. In the current (as of 2/16/21) stable release version of the extension notebook UI is done by a hosted webview, it was the only supported option at the time. As such it is lacking features both of Jupyter and of VS Code editor instances. It does not currently support cutting, copying and pasting of cells.
2. We are currently in the process of moving over to VS Code's new notebook UI that they provide. This allows better UI both for matching Jupyter and supporting more VS Code editor features. This current UI does allow for copying / cutting / pasting cells with the familiar Jupyter commands.

This support will not be added to the old editors, but currently the new UI is available if you use the extension with VS Code - Insiders and will soon start rolling out to VS Code Stable.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/notebooks-are-getting-revamped/

Short answer: Supported with VS Code - Insiders now, and will be supported on stable VS Code in the future.

Comment: I've been using VS code insiders. I'm really liking the new jupyter notebooks interface so far! If I could offer a suggestion, please add in a feature that allows you to interact with the matplotlib charts. Zoom in, zoom out, save as an image, etc.

Comment: Good suggestion, and glad that you like the new interface so far.. If you are interested in plot enhancements you could log an enhancement suggestion here. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues. Customer issues that get the most votes in our issues list we tend to pull into our work backlog. We don't really track stack overflow issues officially (I just help out here as I can) so GitHub is the place to make sure the issue gets noticed.

Comment: I just wanted to ask if there was any update of when the new UI would roll out to stable VS code? I just updated today and copy-pasting cells still does not work. Thanks for the great extension!

Answer (score 0):

The new version of the visual studio Jupyter Notebook extension support all the standard operations for one or multiple cells of the jupyter notebook. For example, the following list shows some tested shutcuts:

- To `copy` a selected cell(s) use: `ctrl+c`
- To `paste` a selected cell(s) use: `ctrl+v`
- To `cut` a selected cell(s) use: `ctrl+x`
- To `delete` a selected cell(s) use: `ctrl+x`
- etc.

Note that, as usual, to select multiples cells one should hold the `ctrl` button before selecting.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2021-01-14, you can now select the cells, right click on any single one of the cells you selected (this will select them as a group if you select more than one) and have the option to press **COPY**. Or you can simply **ctrl+C** as a keyboard shortcut. The key here is when you copy and paste the cells to another notebook, your cursor needs to be outside any cells; that is you need to press somewhere outside the cell before pasting. In COLAB notebook, even if your cursor is on a cell, the copy and pasting method works. BUT here if you do that you will be pasting all of the codes inside the cell where your cursor is active; it will not paste the actual cells you copied.

Hope this wasn't too confusing.